# when triangular input is given to differentiator how will you get square wave output

Tags: operational-amplifier

I searched so many sites they are explaining with the help of pure maths so some one help me what actually happens conceptually.

Comment: Can't explain differentiation or integration without calculus. That's the actual physics.

Comment: What do you get when you integrate a constant?  int(A,t) = At (+C), a Ramp. What happens when you differentiate a ramp?  diff(At,t) = A, a constant.  Now if the gradient of the ramp changes +At, -At then the diff of this will be: +A, -A... a squarewave (ignoring practical slews)

Comment: Probably your best bet at understanding an integrator without involving calculus is the interactive demo at https://www.wisc-online.com/learn/career-clusters/stem/sse5303/the-integrator-op-amp

It also happens to use square and triangle waves as examples.

They also have a similar page on the differentiator

https://www.wisc-online.com/learn/technical/electronics-solid-state/sse5203/the-differentiator-op-amp

Comment: On the other hand if actually want to learn about derivatives and integration (anti-derivatives), which is a prerequisite for really understanding how non-sine waves behave through capacitors (because the [capacitor law involves differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#Current.E2.80.93voltage_relation))  then you then you should first read a (couple of) math tutorial(s), such as 
http://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/derivatives-introduction.html and http://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/integration-introduction.html

Answer (score 3):

A differentiator circuit tries to emulate the mathematical function of differentiation therefore, the most likely explanations will delve into this form of mathematical explanation.

In layman terms, a differentiator converts a constant ramp input to a flat dc output. The higher the voltage ramps per second, the higher the dc output level. Clearly, for a triangle wave input there are two ramps; one rising and one falling. This yields two output levels from the differentiator; one positive (related to the rising input) and one negative (related to the falling input)

Thus a triangle wave is converted to a square wave. Here are some other waveforms: -

[image]

- Sine wave differentiates to a cosine wave
- A square wave differentiates to positive and negative pulses
- Triangle differentiates to square

Answer (score 1):

Its probably easier to see how this works with the aid of a diagram. In this particular case you don't need any great knowledge of calculus beyond the fact that the 'differential' is simply the slope of the graph.

[image]

The slope is calculated by measuring how much the voltage changes divided by the amount of time you are measuring the time to make that change. Let's put a few numbers in and see how that would work.

Suppose the triangular wave starts at 0V and after 2 seconds it reaches its maximum value of 10V. The slope will be (10 - 0) (change in voltage)/ 2 (change in time)

This gives a slope of +5 V/S

If we did the same calculation but with a different starting point, say between 5V and 10V we would get exactly the same answer because the slope is always going to be the same not matter how large or small the time or voltage we measure over. With a rising voltage the slope will be positive and with a straight line it will be constant.

Looking at the falling slope the voltage would change from 10V to 0V. i.e. a 'negative' change. The time is still in 'positive' direction. So the slope on the falling edge will be negative  (0 - 10)/2 or -5 V/S.

The result (of the slope values) will be a waveform that switches from a positive value (on the rise ramp) to a negative value (on the fall ramp) and that describes a square wave (because the rise and fall take the same time).

*A couple of things to note:*

(1) It doesn't matter if the triangular wave starts at 0V or a positive or negative voltage. Its the change in voltage and the fact it is linear (a straight line graph) that is important.

(2) The output (squarewave) is out of phase (shifted in time) to the triangular input by 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

@naresh, your question is very relevant and does not deserve negative votes. It is entirely possible these abstract mathematical operations (as well as any other thing in this world) to be explained intuitively.

**The differentiation** is an indicator of *the rate of change* of a quantity. So when a quantity varies linearly in time (increases/decreases at a constant rate), then its derivative has a constant value that is proportional to the rate, and its sign depends on the direction of change (positive - for increasing, negative - for decreasing).

A good example of this is the relationship between the distance (considered as an input variable) and speed (as an output variable) of a uniformly moving car. If you look at the dashboard, you'll see that the mileage-meter reading (the input variable) linearly increases in time, while the speedometer reading (the output variable) stays constant.

**The integration** is just the opposite (dual) - its rate of change is an indicator of the *value* of a constant quantity. Here, when a quantity stays constant in time, then its integral increases/decreases at a constant rate that is proportional to the constant value, and its direction depends on the sign of this value (increasing - for positive, decreasing - for negative).

Now think, in our car analogy, of the speed as of an input variable, and of the distance - as of an output variable. So, you'll see that the speedometer reading (the input variable) stays constant while the mileage-meter reading (the output variable) linearly increases in time.

Comment: This is actually a reasonable explanation of derivation and integration, but is it really on-topic on EE.SE? I assume you know there's a http://math.stackexchange.com...